# How to prove $A\vec{X} = \vec{0}$ has only trivial solution iff $A$ is row equivalent to $I_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume matrix A is square n * n.

$A\vec{X}=\vec{0}$ only have zero solution $\Leftrightarrow $ $A$ is row equivalent to $I_{n}$.

How to proof?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you think of any relevant definitions? For instance, do you know what a nullspace is? Can you think of any properties a matrix _MUST_ have if it is "row equivalent to $I_n$"?

Comment: The statement is not true for rectangular matrices with full row-rank.  Are we supposed to assume that $A$ is square?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I ignored matrix A is n*n .

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $A$ is equivalent to $I$, there are a series of row operations $R_{1},\dots,R_{n}$ such that $R_{n}\cdot\dots\cdot R_{1}A=I$. This is because every row operation can be represented as matrix multiplication.

Comment: You left out an important detail: all of the $R_i$ are invertible.

Comment: @amd Indeed. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Ok, use the many row elementary matrices， I can proof this lemma. Thank.